# Unable to save textfield on node_save()

Tags: 6, nodes

```
   $fbuser = new stdClass();
   $fbuser->first_name = 'abc'; 
   $fbuser->last_name = 'cde';
   $fbuser->location = 'Vas';   
   $fbuser->link = 'http://www.facebook.com'; 
   $fbuser->gender = 'male';
   module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
   $node = new stdClass();
   $node->type = 'profile2';
   node_object_prepare($node); 
   $node->uid = 1;  
   $node->field_profile_fn[0]['value'] = $fbuser->first_name;(textfield)  
   $node->field_profile_ln[0]['value'] = $fbuser->last_name;(textfield)
   $node->field_profile_city[0]['value'] = $fbuser->location;(textfield) 
   $node->field_profile_facebook[0]['value'] = 'http://www.facebook.com';(textfield) 
   $node->field_profile_gender[0]['value'] = $fbuser->gender;(select list) 
   node_save($node);
```

In the above code I am trying to create a new content of type profile2 .
My node is created but some of the fields show empty text like

field_profile_facebook which is textfield does not show value provided above and gives empty text.

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to add the language to your fields:

```
$node->field_profile_fn[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $fbuser->first_name;
```

But even then, this is not the way to go. You should take a look at https://www.drupal.org/documentation/entity-metadata-wrappers

This approach allows you to use something like this:

```
 $wrapper->field_profile_fn->set($fbuser->first_name);
 $wrapper->save();
```

Comment: I am using d6 version not d7

Comment: you have suggested way for Drupal 7 which won't work with d6, but user has asked it for D6 please consider...

Comment: sorry, I didn't noice the D6 tag